# Uber integration on website

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to integrate uber on my website. The first initial steps say i need to open an account and then register the app  inorder to get client id and server token which then are used for authentication. Is it possible to skip this step at all since all i want to do is redirect the user to the login screen where they can login to their account and request a cab, but I do want to pass latitude, longitude as well so its prepopulated once they login [so they dont have to fill in address again]. Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign up for a developer account at [developer.uber.com](https://developer.uber.com) if you wish to access the API so you add an Uber integration your website.

Once you have an account, you can request rides with a specified product and location for various users that visit your website. It's free to sign up, and you can even earn money through the [affiliate program](https://developer.uber.com/docs/affiliate-program).